# deep linking with router flux react native

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-router-flux

I want to implement deep linking with router flux in react native. I've tried several links and libraries but unable to get it work on android.When i type the address, in the browser it does not open in the app. 
Using react-native-router-flux v 4.0.6 and react-native v 0.55.4.

Comment: I think Deeplinking does not work when you type the address in the browser. are you try to open the link from another way?

Comment: When I typed the link in chrome browser,  it doesn't ask me the option for opening the app. 

Also when i type the link in my google app, then it asks me the option to open it in app, where **onComponentDidMount **, I am accepting the url after doing the changes in android manifest file (adding the scheme and host in the intent-filter) as suggested in android official documents.
And is it possible to navigate to my app, when clicking on some link present in my host url as I am unable to achieve it.

Comment: I believe you do this right and when you click a link suggest your app for opened. what's your problem now?

Comment: Let say, I typed some url, which can be handled by my app, but when the pop up for choosing the view option appears, I opted for chrome, my site gets open. Now when i click on any link (which can be handled by my app as well) within the site inside the chrome, the pop up for choosing the app, chrome isn't appearing , as a result gets open in chrome just like a normal website.